# How should my challenge be tagged?

Tags: discussion, support, tags, specific-question

How should I tag [Good Old Suffix Vector](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/75256/43319)?

[I initially](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/75256/1) tagged it [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) because it requires code that is as short and possible, and [logic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logic) because it involves constructing boolean values, and there is no [boolean](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boolean).

[FryAmTheEggman commented](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/75256/good-old-suffix-vector#comment182657_75256): *I believe alternate scoring methods should always be tagged code-challenge.*

So [I added](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/75256/2) [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge), acknoledging that it has a variation on the regular scoring.

This [prompted Mego](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/75256/3) to remove [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf).

[I rolled it back](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/75256/4) because it is indeed a code golf.

[Then I added](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/75256/5) [restricted-source](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-source) because each answer has self-imposed restrictions (the the more restrigtions the better the score).

Finally [Mego removed](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/75256/6) all but [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge), saying *Code golf is for challenges where the scoring is length of code only. Having booleans in the output does not justify using the logic tag. There is no restriction on the source code (i.e. "you cannot use the letter n").*

So, what is community consensus to correct tagging of my challenge?

Comment: I think we should nuke the code challenge tag because every challenge on the site is a code challenge. It's basically a catch-all for any challenge that is code golf plus some other thing. On any other site on the network, a question that falls into two categories would just have two tags. Related: [Is code-challenge necessary?](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/14/18487)

Comment: @Rainbolt I agree, but we can't do that because every challenge must have at least one tag, and so some wouldn't have any.

Comment: Obviously we would have to retag some questions. For example, a code challenge that combined code golf and fastest code would just be tagged code golf and fastest code. Of course, most code challenge are code golf plus some really obscure scoring that only applies to that one question, so most code challenges would probably just end up as a code golf. We would have to read the question to see the real scoring. That's my only hesitation, and I imagine that's why others haven't already culled the code challenge tag.

Comment: @Rainbolt We have a lot of challenges that are completely unrelated to code golf. Creating a specific tag for every challenge type (even if it only has one or two challenges) doesn't make a lot of sense. Having a catch-all is very useful here.

Answer (score 12):

The [code-golf tag wiki excerpt](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/code-golf/info) says:

> Code-golf is a competition to solve a particular problem in the fewest bytes of source code. If you want to score by characters instead of bytes, state this explicitly in the challenge. If source code length is not the primary scoring criterion, consider using another tag instead.

While byte count is *a part* of your score, it's certainly not the *primary scoring criterion*, so I do not think the tag applies.

The [logic tag wiki excerpt](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/logic/info) says:

> Logic questions tend to be questions on a logical process (working through a process with a logical algorithm) or boolean logic (AND, OR, XOR, NOR, etc.).

I'm not sure about this. While it is *possible* to create the output in your challenge using Boolean logic, one can also create it as `[0]*(a-b)+[1]*b`.

Finally, the [restricted-source tag wiki excerpt](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/restricted-source/info) says:

> Imposes a restriction on the source code used to solve the challenge, for example, having no numbers in the source code.

This one definitely does not apply. A language restriction (or rather, creation date penalty) is not a restriction on the source code.